JavaScript code to read data from Previous step in Pentaho
I have input excel and need to read that data inside the Modified JavaScript Value step in Pentaho tool using JavaScript code.
Input excel contains:



Name
City




Vinay
Hyderabad


Ravi
Nizamabad



I tried below code to read data from excel and generate the data in html format inside Modified JavaScript value step in Pentaho tool:
I tried below steps:
1.JavaScript step: First JavaScript step
2.Group By step: Group By
3.Second JavaScript step: SecondJavaScriptStep
4.Output: Output
Please check attached output snap, it's not printing the data of Name and City columns.
Can you please check and guide where I am making the mistake

You are confusing quite a lot of concepts here.
Steps in PDI work on a row by row basis, they don't operate on the entire dataset, but on batches of rows. Rows have fields.
Variables that you read with the getVariable function are not fields in  row, but variables that are either: a) set by a job or transformation that runs prior to that transformation being executed; b) passed as parameters to the transformation; or c) set in a global configuration file.
In your case the code reads the variables Name and City, but those aren't variables, they're fields. As the variables aren't defined, the i you have in the getVariable function is just the default value. Which is why you're getting 1 or 0.
I suggest you first learn how PDI works before trying to do this. A simpler workflow would be the following:
Text file input -> Javascript Step -> Group by step -> Javascript step

The first javascript step merely has
var tr =  <tr><td>" + Name + "</td><td>" + City + "</td></tr>

This step will generate 1 row of HTML for each row of data, called tr.
The group by step then combines them all and uses the tr field to generate a new field, let's call it tbody by concatenating all fields.
Then the last javascript step prepends and appends the start and end code blocks:
var htmlContent = "<html><head><title>Generated HTML</title></head><body><table border='1'><tr><th>Name</th><th>City</th></tr>";

htmlContent += tbody;
htmlContent += </table></body></html>;

Then you can output this to a text file using the Text File output step.

I tried this but it's printing only Name and City. Please check the question I have added all input and output snapshots

You didn’t set the fields in the output of the javascript step. Read the documentation first.
